# FAQ is out of date (rep requirements still refer to private beta levels)

Tags: bug, status-norepro

As in title - the site is now public beta, but the FAQ has not been updated to reflect this.

Specifically, the rep requirements mostly all say `1`, but I can't (for example) vote to close.

Comment: Give it chance. I don't remember exactly when the other sites changed, but they all have sooner rather than later.

Comment: Give what a chance? It's not a toddler trying to walk. It should be an automated part of the switching from private->public - and if that process isn't automated yet, it should still be part of the things-to-do checklist for whoever did the switch.  In any case, I'm just reporting that it hasn't been done yet. I'm not jumping up and down screaming "WHY HAVEN'T YOU CHANGED THE FAQ ALREADY!?!?!?!". Not yet, anyway. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/faq looks correct to me. No repro.

Comment: Yep, it is now.